# WCF PerCall instance server and Dependency Injection using Prism?

Tags: wcf, prism

If I have a client/server type of application built using both Prism and WCF, and I would like on the serverside to have the wcf service to be instatiated per call BUT I would like to use dependency injection (using the UnityContainer in Prism). How could I possibly do this? Should I have a single instance service it would be no problem, but are there any hooks in WCF to allow for a delegate to be called whenever a service is supposed to be instantiated and have this instance returned?

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible!  WCF provides a plugin to the WCF responsibility chain called an [IInstanceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstanceprovider.aspx).  This allows for you to replace the construction with your own.

Someone has implemented this as a service behavior and is available here:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WCFResources/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1252

Comment: Ah, pure genius! :) I somehow totally overlooked that in the documentation. Thanks alot!